# R8169 Unknown Chip XID 5A4 on boot

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu  18.04 on an Asus X570 Motherboard and keep getting this error

R8169 Unknown Chip XID 5A4

The install promptly stops and I get an error message after a few minutes.

Has anyone else seen this problem and have a solution?

Thanks

Chip

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there's a typo and you mean XID 54A. This chip version is supported from kernel version 5.5.